# Create a rule to remove http:// from query string in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I have this coming to my site `success.php?url=http://www.siteurl.com`

I need to make a .htaccess rule to remove http:// from the url parameter. So it turns into `url=www.siteurl.com`

Any ideas about how I could do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)http://(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks that nearly works however the exact url I need help with is:

www.mysite.com/obb/myaccount/library/success.php?one=http://yfrog.com/nls8g0j&two=http://hsdjkahseha.com&three=232&four=2215

Comment: So that should be redirected to: `/obb/myaccount/library/success.php?one=yfrog.com/nls8g0j&two=http://hsdjkahseha.com&three=232&four=2215` OR you want to remove `http://` from 2nd parameter also?

Comment: Yes from the whole url please

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ success.php?url=http://([a-zA-z-/])      [ L ]
```

Comment: OP doesn't need this.